# Could Spider Man Have Saved Gwen Stacy given the "spring constant" of spider silk?

Tags: forces, kinematics, potential, spring

I was looking at some stuff online about Spider Man in the famous scene from the comics where he accidentally breaks Gwen Stacy's neck, because as he shoots his web down to stop her falling from the Brooklyn Bridge, she stops too quickly and basically suffers whiplash.

If we assume the Brooklyn Bridge, and that she fell 42 m, and that she stops in 0.5s, that Gwen masses 50 kg, we can say that

$W = mg$, so $W = (50 kg)(-9.8 m/s^2)$ and that gets us a weight (for Gwen) of 490 N

Gwen falls halfway so that's 42 m. (We are assuming the 84 m height of the Brooklyn Bridge, which is the one in the artwork; I know that some versions of the comic have it as the George Washington, which is much taller). At that point she would be traveling at

${v_f}^2 = {v_i}^2 +2ad \rightarrow {v_f}^2 = 2(-9.8 m/s^2 (42m) \rightarrow {v_f}^2 = -823.2 m/s \rightarrow v_f = 28.69 \ m/s \sim 29 \ m/s$ which is about 65 mph.

So her momentum is $p = mv = (50 kg)(29 m/s) = 1450 \ kg\cdot{\frac{m}{s}}$

$\Delta p = Ft $ and without our 0.5 s assumption we can say

$$ \Delta p = 1450 \ kg\cdot{\frac{m}{s}}$$
$$ 1450 \ kg\cdot{\frac{m}{s}} = F(0.5s) $$
$$ 2900 N = F$$

And that means an acceleration of $a = \frac{F}{m}=\frac{2900}{50}= \ 58 \ m/s^2$

Or about 5.9 gs which is a lot, as I understand it car accidents that cause severe neck injuries are not out not out of the realm of possibility to survive.

But, I wanted to check this problem from the perspective of a spring. Real spider silk can stretch to about 1.4 times its base length. So I wanted to see what spring constant you would need, and if it is enough (assuming a 40% increase in length) to slow Gwen down "comfortably". We will assume that is <5 gs, or $49 m/s^2$ which would mean a force of $(50 \ kg)(49 \ m/s^2) = 2450 \ N$ or less on Gwen.

So I approached this by saying OK, let's assume the web stretches from 42 m to 58.8 m. That's a stretch displacement of -16.8 m. (I am using downwards as negative coordinates btw)

We know the force Gwen is exerting on the web is 490 N, her weight. We know Hooke's Law says $F = -kx$ and we can say that after 16.8 m of displacement we want the force from the web to be equal to that on Gwen at a minimum to stop her acceleration. In fact, it would have to be about twice the force of gravity if we want it to slow her own to zero velocity, since she has a $v_i$ from the fall. The force we need to get her to zero velocity in that distance turns out to be about $25 \ m/s^2 \cdot 50 \ kg = 1250 \ N$

Using Hooke's Law I find that $F = -kx \rightarrow 1250 \ N = -k(-16.8 \ m) \rightarrow k = 74.4 \ N/m $ for a "spring constant" of Spidey's web.

if we add the two forces from web "spring" and the falling Gwen,

$ -kx + mg = F_{net}$ we can plug in the values we have to get

$ -74.4 \ N/m (-16.8 m) - 490 \ N = F_{Net}$

$ 1251.6 - 490 \ N  = 761.6 N $

And we can use that to see what Gwen's acceleration is: $\frac{761.6 \ N}{50 \ kg} = 15.232 \ m/s^2$

This is highish but it is only about 1.5 g, and that's relatively gentle. So it seems Gwen Stacy would survive if Spider Man used real spider silk (or something like it).

So I ask this question wanting to see if there are any major errors in how I approached this. I thought one other way to do it might be using kinetic and potential energy; we know Gwen's KE on the way down and if we treat the web as a spring we want a PE that equals the KE when it stretches 40% or so, and I was curious if that might be a better way to do it. (BTW I saw one video where Kyle Hill from Nerdist does it, but he doesn't walk through the math. He uses (I think) the energy approach).

I'd be curious what other people think.